# Android + Gitlab CI

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, runner

I tryed setting gitlab ci for my android project. I want used sdk from local folder without loading from official server. I created runner my work station. Tell me please how write .gitlab-ci.yml for this?

Answer (score 0):

In GitLab CI/CD, you gitlab-ci.yml should contain **stages**. Each stage should include one or more jobs, notice that these jobs in the same stage running in parallel.

For example, you may have **3 stages**:

1. Build
2. Run unit tests
3. Deploy

In your gitlab-ci.yml includes some commands to run this job within these stages.

I wrote an article for applying GitLab CI/CD in android project, I hope it could help you.

check [part 1](https://proandroiddev.com/devops-understanding-and-applying-ci-cd-pipeline-for-android-developers-part-1-cdbeab424781)

check [part 2](https://proandroiddev.com/devops-understanding-and-applying-ci-cd-pipeline-for-android-developers-part-2-ec5b063c01bc)